# It seems cronjob not running

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7, magento-2.1.3

How can I confirm that all **Cron Jobs** working fine?

As synchronization of accounts stopped suddenly. All things were working fine earlier.

[image: Process list]
 Show processlist  result

Comment: If it was working fine before, did you make any changes in the mean time that could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in your MySQL Database and look for table called `cron_schedule`.

There are all Magento created jobs with timestamp of creation, scheduled, executed and their status.

**Edit:**

To restart the cron service, use:

```
 /etc/init.d/crond restart
```

OR RHEL/CentOS 5.x/6.x user:

```
 service crond restart
```

OR RHEL/Centos Linux 7.x user:

```
 systemctl restart crond.service
```

**NOTE:**

Make sure that you have your cron job properly set-up and is working on the server. Otherwise, none cron will run.

Comment: can I reset all cronjobs ?

Comment: I installed a extension  n98-magerun2  to run a mailchimp cronjob . after running that one cronjob it worked fine but now mailchimp suppose to  run cronjob after every hour. and its not running now

Comment: Where to run that command ?  I am on root directory and its saying   -bash: /etc/init.d/crond: No such file or directory

Comment: I have updated my answer, try one of those dependable on your server environment.

Comment: I  am on live site . will it cause any issue ? I am afraid . and on root directory I have to run ?

Comment: Stopping crond will simply lead to the orphaned process mechanism of your OS triggering. It shouldn't do any damage or downtime, however, I recommend testing it on development environment... You never know and I can't guarantee anything :P

Comment: Okay :D  and I read anywhere of  truncating that table can reset all cronjobs ?

Comment: On local I got   Failed to restart crond.service: Unit crond.service not found.

Comment: Try to run "show processlist" in you MySQL console to see if there is a prolonged process running that is blocking the corn. Also, I think truncating this table is safe to do so and should restart the crons.

Comment: So rather then runing command I should truncate table cron_schedule ? And automatically all things will start again ?

Comment: That's about right. Just make sure that there is no processes that are blocking or stuck. Kill it if there are any.

Comment: I hope it helped you, please mark the answer as accepted to keep the community clean.

Comment: I am looking into it. can you check process list ?  I did  show processlist   on cli in mysql . Is there issue ?

Comment: That look okey :)

Comment: then I should truncate ?  And hopefully will start working normally ?  Should I backup that table ?

Comment: Always make a backup :D  ALWAYS :D Hopefully, it should start working normally.

Comment: Not working still :(

Comment: hymmmm.... Anything in the logs? Try reinstalling the MageRun

Comment: in installed in vendor and added using composer . Not getting command to uninstall it

Comment: Did you manage to get anywhere with it? Also, make sure you have the crons properly set-up on the server, otherwise they won't work... I guess you have them properly set if they were working before but just make sure.

Comment: I didnt properly set them :D that was issue

Comment: haha see... sometimes it's the most obvious thing.... Glad you got it working tho :)

Comment: thank you really for help :)  the developer deployed didn't told me he that he didn't configured all cron jobs actually :P